# For $a,b,c>0$, prove that $\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}\ge a+b+c+\frac{4(a-b)^2}{a+b+c}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> For $a,b,c>0$, prove that $$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}\ge a+b+c+\frac{4(a-b)^2}{a+b+c}.$$
> (Source : Balkan Mathematical Olympiad 2005)

**My work:**

From the given inequality, we can have,

$$\frac{(a-b)^2}{b}+\frac{(b-c)^2}{c}+\frac{(c-a)^2}{a}\ge \frac{4(a-b)^2}{a+b+c}$$

This can be re-written as,

$$(a+b+c)\left(\frac{(a-b)^2}{b}+\frac{(b-c)^2}{c}+\frac{(c-a)^2}{a}\right)\ge 4(a-b)^2$$

Now, what am I supposed to do? I am doubtful whether the question is correct or not. Please help.

EDIT: After checking quite a few cases I conclude that the inequality is actually working. So there might not be any mistakes at all.

Comment: It seems like the $c$ has been suspiciously discriminated. Are you sure that this is the question?

Comment: @chubakueno Yes, this is the question but I am also having the doubt that the question is not correct...I am actually searching for cases where this inequality does not hold to prove that this question is not correct...but if I do not find any such cases then this question will have to be considered correct

Comment: @chubakueno This actually seems to be working...so I assume the question is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from your last one:

LHS$\ge (|a-b|+|b-c|+|c-a|)^2 \ge (|a-b|+|b-c+c-a|)^2=4(a-b)^2$

Comment: You used Cauchy inequality...did you?

Comment: yes.it is.I didn't list the "=" condition because I thought you could find by your self as your effort show your ability.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution...