# Prove $\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\ge 4+(x-y)^2$ for positives $4 \le x + y + z \le 5$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $x,y,z>0$, and such $$4\le x+y+z\le 5.$$
> Show that
> $$\dfrac{x^2}{y}+\dfrac{y^2}{z}+\dfrac{z^2}{x}\ge 4+(x-y)^2.$$

It seems that the condition $\dfrac{x^2}{y}+\dfrac{y^2}{z}+\dfrac{z^2}{x}\ge 4+(x-y)^2$ is maybe old, and this condition is strange?
http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=586357 .
I want to use
$$\dfrac{x^2}{y}=2x-y+\dfrac{(x-y)^2}{y}.$$

If we let $$x\to x'r,y\to y'r,z\to z'r,$$then $$x'+y'+z'=4, r\in [1,\dfrac{5}{4}]$$
But I can't prove that either, because I felt I can't use the condition.

Thank you.

Comment: The last equation is proven by subtracting $2x$, adding $y$ and writing the LHS as one fraction. This will be $\frac{x^2-2xy+y^2}{y}$.

Comment: can you post all full solution?

Comment: @Jasper he already knows how to prove the equality. What he meant was that he hadn't found a way to prove the whole inequality using the equality.

Comment: Well, now I feel quite silly :D I don't have a solution, sorry.

Comment: My suspicion is that the $\leq 5$ bound is a red herring. Do you have an equality case that is not $x=y=z = \frac{4}{3}$?

Comment: Hello,@Calive Lin I don't understand you meaning

Comment: @CalvinLin I think there are no other equality cases as long as $x+y+z \in [4, 5]$.  However outside that interval, equality is possible for (I think) any positive value of $x+y+z$. Hence the inequality doesn't hold if you remove the upper bound of $5$.

Comment: @CalvinLin The upper bound of $5$ is not that much of a red herring, as when $x=0.54,y=3.16,z=1.35$, the inequality becomes false, but the sum $x+y+z=5.05$ is remarkably near to $5$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy How did you find the counter-example?

Comment: @Sawarnik with the help of PARI-GP on my computer

Comment: Is there any way to use symmetry to help simplify the problem? The choice of variables $x,y$ on the right side is clearly arbitrary, the same inequality must hold for $x,z$ or $y,z$ as well.

Comment: I haven't tried to finish this approach but anyway: Writing $(x, y, z)=r(x', y', z')$ with $x'+y'+z'=4, r \in [1, \frac{5}{4}]$, we may view (for fixed $x', y', z'$) the inequality as a quadratic in $r$, so to prove that the quadratic in $r$ is $\leq 0$ for $r \in [1, \frac{5}{4}]$, it suffices to prove that it is $\leq 0$ for $r=1$ and for $r=\frac{5}{4}$. This means it suffices to consider the two cases $x+y+z=4$ and $x+y+z=5$. The first case ($x+y+z=4$) is relatively easy to do, but I haven't tried to prove the inequality for the second case $x+y+z=5$.

Comment: The inequality is true when: $$\frac{4}{3}\leq \{x,y,z\}\leq \frac{5}{3}$$

Comment: Balkan MO 2005, P3 asks to prove :
$\dfrac{x^2}{y}+\dfrac{y^2}{z}+\dfrac{z^2}{x}\ge x+y+z+\dfrac{4(x-y)^2}{x+y+z}$
Now we can use it to prove this inequality. The RHS is convex in $x+y+z$. So if we can show that RHS$\ge 4+(x-y)^2$ i.e the minimum occurs when $x+y+z=4$ then we are done. But it leads to the inequality $(x-y)^2\le 5$ but it is not always true. I know this is not a solution, and that convex function part is probably wrong but still something to think about. :)

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670592/for-a-b-c0-prove-that-fraca2b-fracb2c-fracc2a-ge-abc-f

Answer (score 3):

## Notes

Pardon my long, long answer (I struggle to be concise). I'll give my best to make my answer simple, clear, and easy to understand.

Because this is a rather "confusing" problem, I cannot provide an extremely concrete proof - part of this might need your intuition's help to make sense (sorry!).

**EDIT**: I also do realize that this answer is, in great parts, incomplete in that it does not make use of $x + y + z \ge 4$. That is a problem because we know well of many examples that don't satisfy this inequality for $x + y + z < 4$, e.g. $(1, 1, 1)$. It would really help me as well if you can find the little gap in my logic for me, thanks!

Please do correct me if you find anything in my solution that is causing a problem. This is, after all, just my weak attempt at tackling this 1k-view question.

## My Work

To start with, we know we want to prove

$$\frac{x^2}y + \frac{y^2}z + \frac{z^2}x \ge 4 + (x-y)^2$$

We can multiply the entire inequality by $xyz$, and we know we can do that without needing to change the signs because we are given that $x, y, z > 0$. Thus, we get

$$x^3z + y^3x + z^3y \ge 4xyz + xyz(x^2 - 2xy + y^2)$$
$$x^3z + y^3x + z^3y \ge 4xyz + x^3yz - 2x^2y^2z + y^3xz$$

We'll be working from that. From the second given, we know that

$$x + y + z <= 5$$

As we also know that $x, y, z > 0$ (Note that $x, y, z \neq 0$). From some basic reasoning (or, if you insist, simple algebra), you can realize that

$$x, y, z < 5$$

We'll then start by breaking the inequality down into parts, labeled as follows:

$$x^3z + y^3x + z^3y \ge 4xyz + x^3yz - 2x^2y^2z + y^3xz$$
$$\underbrace{x^3z + y^3x + z^3y}_A \ge \underbrace{4xyz + x^3yz + y^3xz}_B + \underbrace{(-2x^2y^2z)}_C$$
$$A \ge B + C$$

### Group $A$

We can first find an inequality to describe $A$. Because we know $x, y, z < 5$, we can be completely sure that $x^3z, y^3x, z^3y < 5^4$, or $x^3z + y^3x + z^3y < 3 \cdot 5^4$. So we know:

$$A < 3 \cdot 5^4$$
$$A < 1875$$

### Group $B$

To describe $B$, we do, essentially, the same thing. We break the group down into parts:

$$4xyz < 4 \cdot 5^3$$
$$x^3yz, y^3xz < 5^5$$

We sum the three to get:

$$B < 4 \cdot 5^3 + 2\cdot 5^5$$
$$B < 6750$$

### Group $C$

While finding an inequality for $C$, we must remember that $C$ is negative. Keep in mind, therefore, that the signs will be flipped. We know $x^2y^2z < 5^5$. We multiply both sides by $-2$ and flip the inequality sign to get

$$-2x^2y^2z > -2\cdot 5^5$$

$$C > -6250$$

## Simplifying the Problem

Alright now. With our inequalities, **I think** it makes sense to say that we can prove the main inequality by proving our "reworded" inequality

$$A \ge B + C$$

given the three conditions

$$A < 1875$$
$$B < 6750$$
$$C > -6250$$

Seriously, correct me if I'm wrong here. I really could be - it almost seems so confusing.

### The Final Proof

Let's first plug in the inequality for $A$ and simplify.

$$1875 > A \ge B + C$$
$$1875 > B + C$$

Then, we can subtract $B$ from both sides and plug in $C$'s inequality and simplify again:

$$1875 - B > C$$
$$1875 - B > C > -6250$$
$$1875 - B > -6250$$

Lastly, we add $B$ and $6250$ to both sides to simplify:

$$1875 + 6250 > B$$
$$8125 > B$$

**I would think**, then, that all we need do is to show $$8125 > B$$ for all $B < 6750$. This is easily done because we know that anything less than $6750$ is also less than $8125$. So I'd think it's proved.

But again, this, for one, seems too ambiguous logically - and, all the while, too simple.

I also, again, notice that I did not make use of $x + y + z \ge 4$ - so I'm almost sure some part of this proof is drastically misled. However, for now, this is the best I can give - please, please, please do point out any mistake you find in my work - it'd help me too!

Comment: Yes, it would suffice to prove $A\ge B+C$ given $A<1875$, $B<6750$ and $C>-6250$. However, your further reasoning is incorrect - $1875 > A\ge B+C\implies 1875>B+C$, but $1875 > A\ge B+C\not\iff 1875>B+C$. It is sufficient to prove that $1875>A\ge B+C$, but it is not sufficient to prove $1875>B+C$, since $1875>B+C$ does not imply $1875>A\ge B+C$ - $1875>B+C$ does not tell us anything about $A$. This mistake is found in one of the other steps of your proof after that as well (by the way, $\not\iff$ denotes '_not if and only if_', but I don't know how to put it in LaTeX properly).

Comment: Oh, yes. I see now. I'm wondering if the other inequality $x + y + z \ge 4$ can come in there.

Comment: I have noticed you've never used @username on this site, which is important, since otherwise the person you reply to does not get a notification indicating your reply and hence likely misses out on reading your comment.

Comment: This, however, is not necessary when you are commenting under the person's post (as you can see by getting a notification notifying about this comment).

Comment: @mathh Oh, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give a full proof but here is a piece that might take you closer to what you're looking for.

Using the equality you have given, we can transform the left-hand side of the equation to the form
$$\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x} = 2x - y + \frac{(x-y)^2}{y} + 2y - z + \frac{(y-z)^2}{z} + 2z - x + \frac{(z-x)^2}{x} = x + y + z + \frac{(x-y)^2}{y} + \frac{(y-z)^2}{z} + \frac{(z-x)^2}{x} $$
Since we know that $x+y+z \geq 4$, we get
$$\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x} \geq 4 +  \frac{(x-y)^2}{y} + \frac{(y-z)^2}{z} + \frac{(z-x)^2}{x}$$

So, in order to prove the given inequality, it is sufficient to prove that 
$$\frac{(x-y)^2}{y} + \frac{(y-z)^2}{z} + \frac{(z-x)^2}{x} \geq (x-y)^2$$
This inequality can be rewritten as
$$(x-y)^2 \left(\frac{1}{y} - 1 \right) + \frac{(y-z)^2}{z} + \frac{(z-x)^2}{x} \geq 0$$

Since any square $x^2 \geq 0$ and $x,y,z > 0$, this inequality certainly holds when 
$$\frac{1}{y} - 1 \geq 0$$ or in other words when $0 < y \leq 1$.

However, this is a rather strict condition that was not actually given. Additionally, the condition $x+y+z \leq 5$ was not used anywhere in here - and as @EwanDelanoy pointed out, it seems to be crucial.

Comment: It's interesting that your answer doesn't use x+y+z <= 5, while mine **only** uses that and doesn't use x+y+z >= 5.

Comment: @KyeWShi You've mistyped one of the last symbols, i.e. it is <=5 (nitpicking, but this is to avoid confusion).

Comment: Oops, you're right. Wait, I don't know how to edit...

Comment: @KyeWShi Editing your own comment is only possible for a limited amount of time, which is about $5$-$10$ minutes after you have posted it, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

*Remarks*: Here is a proof. We motivate our proof using computer.

We have the following identity
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}
 - 4 - (x-y)^2\right)xyz(x + y + z)^2\\[6pt]
 ={}& 4(5 - x - y - z)^2 \cdot \left[y \left( xy-{z}^{2} \right) ^{2}+x \left( xz+{y}^{2}-2\,yz \right) ^{2
 }+z \left( {x}^{2}-2\,xy+yz \right) ^{2}\right]\\[6pt]
 &\quad
 + (5 - x - y - z)(x + y + z - 4) \cdot f(x, y, z)\\[6pt]
 &\quad
 + (x+y+z-4)^2\cdot g(x, y, z)
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
f(x, y, z) &:= 9\,{x}^{4}z-39\,{x}^{3}yz+9\,{x}^{3}{z}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2}{y}^{3}+64\,{x}^
{2}{y}^{2}z-16\,{x}^{2}y{z}^{2}\\
&\qquad +9\,x{y}^{4}-39\,x{y}^{3}z-16\,x{y}^{2}
{z}^{2}+xy{z}^{3}+9\,{y}^{2}{z}^{3}+9\,y{z}^{4},\\[6pt]
g(x, y, z) &:= 5\,{x}^{4}z-24\,{x}^{3}yz+5\,{x}^{3}{z}^{2}+5\,{x}^{2}{y}^{3}+42\,{x}^
{2}{y}^{2}z-8\,{x}^{2}y{z}^{2}\\
&\qquad +5\,x{y}^{4}-24\,x{y}^{3}z-8\,x{y}^{2}{z
}^{2}+xy{z}^{3}+5\,{y}^{2}{z}^{3}+5\,y{z}^{4}.
\end{align*}

We can prove that $f(x, y, z) \ge 0$ and $g(x, y, z) \ge 0$ for all $x, y, z \ge 0$. Indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
 f(x, y, z) &= \frac{119}{576}yz^4 + \frac{1}{576}y(72xy - 71z^2)^2 + \frac{1}{24}yz^2(12x + z)^2 \\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \frac14x(6xz + 6y^2 - 13yz)^2 + \frac{41}{63}x^4z + \frac{1}{112}x^2z(6x - 7y)^2\\[6pt]
 &\qquad  + \frac{1}{144}z(34x^2 - 81xy + 36yz)^2, \\[6pt]
 g(x, y, z) &= \frac{1}{20}y(10xy - xz - 10z^2)^2 + \frac{1}{500}x(50xz + 35y^2 - 84yz)^2 \\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \frac{51}{500}xy^2(5y - 12z)^2 + \frac{1}{8000}z(175x^2 - 536xy + 200yz)^2\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \frac{44}{1875}x^2y^2z + \frac{1}{120000}x^2z(375x - 88y)^2.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

Considering

$$
f = \dfrac{x^2}{y}+\dfrac{y^2}{z}+\dfrac{z^2}{x}-4-(x-y)^2 = 0
$$

and the plane

$$
p_{\lambda} = x + y + z - \lambda = 0
$$

making $x=y=z$ we have

$$
\cases{
f(z,z,z) = 3z-4=0\\
p_{\lambda}(z,z,z) = 3z-\lambda=0  
}
$$

then the point $\left(\frac 43,\frac 43,\frac 43\right)$ is common to

$$
\cases{
f(x,y,z) = 0\\
p_{4}(x,y,z) = 0
}
$$

Now taking the gradient and hessian of $f$ at $\left(\frac 43,\frac 43,\frac 43\right)$ we have

$$
\nabla f = (1,1,1)
$$

$$
H_f = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 1 & -\frac{3}{2} \\
 -\frac{3}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

with eigenvalues $\left(\frac 92,\frac 12,0\right)$ hence $f, p_{4}$ are tangent at $\left(\frac 43,\frac 43,\frac 43\right)$